# How do I export multiple objects to raster images from Illustrator cs5?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, export, raster

I need to export multiple objects from Illustrator to individual `.png` files. The objects are different in size.

I know this is easily done from Inkscape, but Illustrator seems to produce nicer images.

What is the routine to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are they all in one document?  if so, you could create multiple artboards and place each object in it's own artboard.  then do file / export, choose format:png and check the box for "use artboards".  this will export each artboard to it's own png file.

or you can try exporting layers directly using [this script](http://www.ericson.net/content/2011/06/export-illustrator-layers-andor-artboards-as-pngs-and-pdfs/) (I have not tested it).

Comment: I`d say this is just an alternative to creating a separate file for every object, rather than productivity solution. If I change the proportions of an object, I have to adapt artboard to it and it isn`t very attractive.

Comment: see revised answer